# iTextSharp : several lines in the same cell

Tags: c#, reporting, itext

I have a table and I'd like in the same cell have 2 lines(ex: "MyLine" and on the second line "MySecondLine"). Is there a way to do this ? May be there is a kind of "carriage return" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the new line character of #?

In Java, it should be "\n".

Comment: You are completely right. Don't know why I was sure that's ... not working ;-) thanks.